# Mobile browsers, what to support?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I wanted to ask what other people in the industry are doing with regards mobile browser support and is there any way of being able to understand the breakdown of what actual browsers people are using and not simply their OS, for example I have Safari, Opera, Chrome and Skyfire installed on my iPhone and tend to use Chrome most of the time.

I assume that they will still render differently?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks